# Looking for a word or short expression to it for wanting to re-experience something for the first time

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

We all have the wish to experience something for the first time **again** but obviously it's not possible.

How can we describe that wish/feeling ?

Is there a specific word, or a combination of words that could perfectly describe this.

Comment: According to UD, 'First Timer Syndrome' is already taken.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth its more in the sense that you wish you could experience for the first time again. For example, you wish you could feel again what you had felt when you listened to your favorite song

Comment: Yes; I'm saying that this phrase / compound noun shouldn't be re-defined for **your** sense. I'll add "I don't know of any such term; there may well be none" before someone gives it as another unsuitable answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [**rediscover**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rediscover) (*verb*)
> to discover (something lost or forgotten) again

*Discover* is the action of finding or experiencing something for the first time, so *rediscover* is a simple way to convey the same thing happening again. It's not necessarily a feeling itself, but you could say something like

> The feeling of rediscovery...